# Move Image inside a View

Tags: swiftui

I just want to move an Image on the top side on the screen. I want to achieve something like [this](https://mobbin.com/screens/2e064c90-dd17-4c37-a079-869d20518a46). I want my CentralCardView() to be in the middle, and the Amazon Forest image on the top side of the screen, just like in the image. I tried with .offset, but I want to move all the view.

Here's my code

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color("whiteBackground").ignoresSafeArea()
        
            Image("amazonForest")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: .infinity, height: 400)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
        CentralCardView()
}
```

Here's my CentralCardView()

```
struct CentralCardView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .foregroundColor(Color("logoColor"))
                .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
                .shadow(radius: 10)
            
            HStack {
                Image("appLogoWhite")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Inizia a riciclare. ♻️")
                        .font(.custom(FontsManager.SenkronBlokBold.regular, size: 20))
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                    
                    Text("Scopri come fare cliccando qui.")
                        .font(.custom("NoyhSlim-Semilight", size: 20))
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                }
                
                Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do it? It should be and easy stuff but I'm losing my mind.

What I got:

[image]

Comment: Yup. I'm sorry, I'm Italian and miss clicked.

Comment: At the least, you'd want `CentralCardView` inside the `ZStack`. Hard to say more since you haven't included a [mre] and we don't know the layout properties of `CentralCardView`

Comment: Added to the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified example, since we don't have your images:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            Color.white.ignoresSafeArea()
            
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                Rectangle().fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(height: 400)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                CentralCardView()
                    .padding(.bottom, -50)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This uses `ZStack` to overlay content and a negative padding with a `bottom` alignment to put the card at the bottom of the "image" (represented here by the `Rectangle`)

[image]

Comment: That looks ok, but, how can i Move this green rectangle on top of the screen ignoring safe area?

Comment: Change the `alignment` of the first `ZStack` to `top` -- I've edited the answer to show that.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color("whiteBackground").ignoresSafeArea()
        
        VStack {
            Image("amazonForest")
                .resizable()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, idealHeight: 200)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            Spacer()
        }
        
        CentralCardView()
    }
}
```

I replaced the `ZStack` with a `VStack`, which arranges its children in a vertical stack.

Placed the `Image` inside the `VStack` and set its frame to take the entire width and have an ideal height of 200 points, effectively showing the image at the top half of the screen.
Added a Spacer after the image to push the CentralCardView to the bottom half of the screen.
With these modifications, the image will be displayed at the top of the screen or the top half of the screen as per the requirement.

Comment: Just remember that 200 points on an iPad look quite different than 200 points on an iPhone SE

Comment: Mh, this doesn't work. I want to "move" my image on top side of the screen, and the CentralCardView() should be in the center of the screen, just by the bottom part of the image